# jhipster mvn package liquibase:update gives error but updates database

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I created a basic jhipster app, but instead H2 database I chose a postgresql database. I properly configured it and after run **mvn liquibase:update** from my sts 3.9 I get these test fails. Yet the command successfully updates my database, but I am concerned with the error list.

```
   assertThatUserCanBeFoundByEmailIgnoreCase(com.jhipster.example.security.DomainUserDetailsServiceIntTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)



Running com.jhipster.example.security.SecurityUtilsUnitTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec - in com.jhipster.example.security.SecurityUtilsUnitTest
Running com.jhipster.example.security.jwt.JWTFilterTest
2018-06-12 10:15:52.900  INFO 9992 --- [           main] c.j.example.security.jwt.TokenProvider   : Invalid JWT token.
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.342 sec - in com.jhipster.example.security.jwt.JWTFilterTest
Running com.jhipster.example.security.jwt.TokenProviderTest
2018-06-12 10:15:54.528  INFO 9992 --- [           main] c.j.example.security.jwt.TokenProvider   : JWT token compact of handler are invalid.
2018-06-12 10:15:54.531  INFO 9992 --- [           main] c.j.example.security.jwt.TokenProvider   : Expired JWT token.
2018-06-12 10:15:54.534  INFO 9992 --- [           main] c.j.example.security.jwt.TokenProvider   : Invalid JWT signature.
2018-06-12 10:15:54.539  INFO 9992 --- [           main] c.j.example.security.jwt.TokenProvider   : Invalid JWT token.
2018-06-12 10:15:54.542  INFO 9992 --- [           main] c.j.example.security.jwt.TokenProvider   : Unsupported JWT token.
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec - in com.jhipster.example.security.jwt.TokenProviderTest
Running com.jhipster.example.service.MailServiceIntTest
```

Also I noticed the info about jwt problems, why is that?

Comment: The JWT problems are because you are running the tests (TokenProviderTest) which ensure bad tokens are not accepted

Comment: thanks. what about the load AplicationContext error?